# Angular Daterangepicker in a popover not showing in the correct place

Tags: css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, daterangepicker

I am using ng2-daterangepicker to show a date range picker in a pop-over.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Component({
  selector: "protocol-details",
  providers: [PatientsService],
  template: `

        <div *ngIf="data == null ;then content else table_content"></div>

        <ng-template #content>
            No Accruals
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #table_content> 
          <div class="container">
            <div class="center">
                <h3 style="color:#215081;"> Protocol Accrual for {{mdg}} for Protocol No. {{protocolNumber}}</h3>
            </div>
            <br> 

              <div class="form-group">
                <div style="position:relative"> 
                  <div class="input-group" daterangepicker (selected)="selectedDate($event, mainInput)"
                  (cancelDaterangepicker)="calendarEventsHandler($event)"
                  (applyDaterangepicker)="calendarEventsHandler($event)"
                  (hideDaterangepicker)="calendarEventsHandler($event)"
                  (showDaterangepicker)="calendarEventsHandler($event)"
                  >
                      <span class="form-control uneditable-input"  name="daterange" >
                          {{ mainInput.start | date:'M/dd/y' }} - {{ mainInput.end| date:'M/dd/y' }}
                      </span>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <a type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a>
                      </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </ng-template>
```

My styles are :

```
styles: [ `

      main {
        padding: 1em;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: block;
        max-width: 600px;
      }

    .well {
      min-height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      background-color: #EDEDED;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 1px 1px inset;
      padding: 19px;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
      border-image: initial;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }

    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .containerDiv {
      margin: auto;
      width: 60%;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .container { margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; *zoom: 1;} 

    .label-primary {
      background-color: #337ab7;
    }

    .label {
      display: inline;
      padding: .2em .6em .3em;
      font-size: 100%;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      border-radius: .25em;
    }

    p{
      display:inline;
      color: #595959; 
    }

    h3{
      color: #808080; 
    }

    span {
      font-size: xx-large; 
    }

    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .glyphicon {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

  ` ]
```

I see that onclick the range picker is rendered at (0,0) so the left and top values of the popup are not being set.

Screen looks like :

[image: Datrange picker showing on the top left]

I have tried to wrap this in a div with relative positioning but that did not solve the issue.

Can someone please suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Bootstrap 4 in this case?

Comment: I am using ng2-daterangepicker . https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker